# Redirect all routes to main page except two routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, model-view-controller, routes

In mvc 4 application i need to redirect users to main page, except login and signup page.

Whenever a request comes except login or register, i need to redirect user to homepage permenantly.

For example

```
www.example.com/home/contact
```

should redirect to
    www.example.com

Only these two address will be avaliable for user:

```
www.example.com/user/login
www.example.com/user/register
```

How can i handle this in shortest way. I dont want to change all controller methods.

Comment: Do you understand sessions and cookies? Perhaps you only want to redirect to those urls when the user is not logged in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You create redirect controller

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult News()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("/News");
    }
}
```

in your RouteConfig you make routes for your urls

```
       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "userlogin",
          url: "/user/login",
          defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login" }
       );

       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "UserRegister",
          url: "/user/register",
          defaults: new {  controller = "User", action = "register" }
        );

       MapRoute("Default", new {controller="Redirect", action="News"});
```

That way everything will redirect except for your 2 urls.

Answer (score 0):

In `javascript` I recommend using this method.

`window.location.replace(...)`